# Mylyn connector for sourceforge feature/bug tracking system

Tags: eclipse, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, mylyn, sourceforge

I haven't found any clear information about this around.

Is it possible to integrate the sourceforge tracking system for bugs/features with Mylyn?

I've found [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Sourceforge_with_Mylyn) page that seems a bit old (indeed the link for downloading the general connector does not work).

Anyone have a clue about this? It is possible to realise such a kind of connection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes with the move of SourceForge to use Allura the configuration on the page you highlighted is outdated.

I posted details on getting the Web Template Connector to work for Allura at http://officefloor.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/allura-sourceforge-mylyn-connector/

Answer (score 1):

The generic connector is now in the Mylyn incubator.  Use this download site:
   http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/incubator/3.7  (for Eclipse 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

Answer (score 0):

Since I wasn't able to get it running – maybe it's because of Eclipse Luna or something else – I slightly modified [Daniel's method](http://officefloor.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/allura-sourceforge-mylyn-connector/) which partially uses the REST interface:

### Basic Configuration

1. Add the following parameters and appropriate values to the table unter *Additional Settings* section in the *Properties for Task Repository* dialog:

   - *project* – your so-called UNIX name of the project
   - *tickets* – the ticketing application, e.g. *bugs* or *features*
   - *bearer_token* – you need to set-up a bearer token as described in [the Allura documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Allura%20API/#oauth-with-bearer-tokens)
2. under *Advanced Configuration*, use:

   - *Task URL*: `${serverUrl}/p/${project}/${tickets}/` (the same as in Daniel's method)
   - *New Task URL*: `${serverUrl}/p/${project}/${tickets}/new` (the same as in Daniel's method)
   - *Query Request URL*: `${serverUrl}/rest/p/${project}/${tickets}?access_token=${bearer_token}`
   - *Query Pattern*: `\{"summary":\s*"({Description}.+?)",\s*"ticket_num":\s*({Id}.+?)\}`

### Milestone query

To query tasks by milestones, use the following parameters in your *Edit Query* configuration:

- add a parameter *milestone* with e.g. *M1* to the parameter table
- use the following *Query URL*: `${serverUrl}/rest/p/${project}/${tickets}/search?q=_milestone%3A${milestone}&access_token=${bearer_token}`